# Trying to use a SQL stored procedure in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures

The following code is causing problem in my Windows Forms app:

```
SqlConnection cnnDB = new SqlConnection(<connection string>);
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = cnnDB.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_ProcName";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@int1", ComboBox1.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@int2", ComboBox2.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@int3", ComboBox3.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@int4", ComboBox4.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar1", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar2", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar3", ComboBox5.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar4", stringVariable);
    cnnDB.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnnDB.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This is what happens when I execute it:

1. If `stringVariable` is either "Insert" or "Update", data from TextBox1 and TextBox2 isn't passed to procedure.
2. If `stringVariable` is "Delete", I get error “Procedure or function ‘sp_ProcName’ expects parameter ‘@varchar3’, which was not supplied”.

Is there something wrong with the code?

EDIT: As requested by @Steve and @MethodMan, below is the stored procedure in SQL Server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ProcName]
(
      @int1 int,
      @int2 int,
      @int3 int,
      @int4 int,
      @varchar1 varchar(7),
      @varchar2 varchar(6),
      @varchar3 nvarchar(10),
      @varchar4 nvarchar(10) = ''
)
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     IF @varchar4 = 'Insert'
     BEGIN
          INSERT INTO Table1(int1,int2,int3,int4,varchar1,varchar2,varchar3)
          VALUES(@int1,@int2,@int3,@int4,@varchar1,@varchar2,@varchar3)
     END
     IF @varchar4 = 'Update'
     BEGIN
          UPDATE Table1
               SET int1=@int1, int2=@int2, int3=@int3, int4=@int4, varchar1=@varchar1, varchar2=@varchar2, varchar3=@varchar3
          WHERE varchar1 = @varchar1
     END
     IF @varchar4 = 'Delete'
     BEGIN
          DELETE FROM Table1
          WHERE varchar1 = @varchar1
     END
```

Well, after a closer examination, I see that the Update part in stored procedure is "bad egg". I'll need to find some other way. Delete part too.

P.S. Sorry for long question.

Comment: I think you should show the code of the StoredProcedure to better understand your problem

Comment: Do your ComboBoxes have a DataSource and ValueMember set?  AddWithValue doesn't work too well with "object", which is what SelectedValue is trying to return.

Comment: in order for anyone to answer this properly you need to show the full stored procedure also the error is telling you exactly what the issue is. if you declare parameters, then you must pass in all parameters if not take the advice of the posted answer and use `Default Values`

Comment: @LarsTech, yes, all ComboBoxes have set DataSource and ValueMember, and the data manipulation works in case of Insert and Delete

Comment: @MethodMan well, that is the problem. For some reason ComboBox5 doesn't pass anything, even when I select it from drop down list.

Comment: Can you be certain that their is a value being passed in the drop down. If its required and the drop down is null you will likely get the exact same error.

Comment: @logixologist Well, for 'Insert' I'm certain because when I check the DB in SSMS the new record is there. Update needs rework, but dunno how, somewhere it's recommended to use surrogate keys or something like that. And delete works with previously entered records except in case when varchar1 and varchar2 are null...

Comment: so @varchar1 is what is common between all those records?  Remember the where clause is going to filter out those records you  want updated. A good test is if you can remove the Update or Delete and replace it with a select, would you really want to update those records/. In fact before I do a delete I always do a SELECT * FROM with the same where clause to see what records I am about to effect.

Comment: @logixologist the varchar1 and varchar2 columns have the unique constraint, so if I use SELECT with WHERE clause that's in the procedure I'll get a single row. On the other hand, I think I'll have to include a primary key column in a winforms app, because the stored procedure present has anomaly in the update section. also it'll be much more safer :(

Comment: Well, it seems that the universal procedure for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE can't be used in this case, I'll have to separate them into 3 stored procedures. Simply said they require different parameters, which can't be all in one basket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` or assign **default values** to your stored procedure parameters that might be missing:

**Method 1 :**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[problemParam] 
    // Other parameters go here then
    @varchar1 NVARCHAR(50) = null, 
    @varchar1 NVARCHAR(50) = null,
    @varchar1 NVARCHAR(50) = null, 
AS  
BEGIN
  -- Procedure Logic go here
END
```

**Method 2:**

```
object param1 = DBNull.Value;
object param2 = DBNull.Value;
object param3 = DBNull.Value;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    param1 = TextBox1.Text;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
    param2 = TextBox2.Text;

if(ComboBox5.SelectedValue != null)
    param3 = TextBox1.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar1", param1 );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar2", param2 );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varchar3", param3 );
```